# Wrapping HTML markup in XML with CData in Java

Tags: java, html, xml, encode, cdata

I am converting XML to HTML and I need to wrap the HTML content with `<![CDATA[`...`]]>` (this is a requirement).

I figured I can leverage a Java static method which lists all the children of a specified node, using org.w3c.dom, for this task.

```
private static void showAllChildren(NodeList nodeList) {
    if (nodeList != null && nodeList.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node tempNode = nodeList.item(i);

            if (tempNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                System.out.println("\nNode Name: " + tempNode.getNodeName() + " [OPEN]");
                System.out.println("Node Value: " + tempNode.getTextContent());
            }

            if (tempNode.hasChildNodes()) {
                showAllChildren(tempNode.getChildNodes(), doc);
            }

            System.out.println("Node Name: " + tempNode.getNodeName() + " [CLOSE]");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a sample XML file:

```
<content>
    <records>
        <record>
            <param1>A1</param1>
            <param2>
                <div><p>this html that should be wrapped with CDATA</p></div>
            </param2>
            <param3>
                <table><tr><td>this html that should be wrapped with CDATA, as well</td></tr></table>
            </param3>
        </record>
    </records>
</content>
```

**Does there a exist a Java library or method or some means which can scan the XML file and distinguish XML markup from HTML markup and appropriately wrap the HTML markup with I am converting XML to HTML and I need to wrap the html content with CDATA?**

Sure, with this particular XML example, I could write code to look for param XML tags and wrap whatever inside them with `<![CDATA[`...`]]>`. But it would be much easier if there was a way to automatically scan for and wrap HTML markup, especially if the XML file structure changes in the future. It would make maintenance a lot easier.

Thank you very much.